# What is regression testing and its automation in web-development?

Tags: web-services, automation, automated-tests

Let's suppose we're talking about a microservices-based web-application developed by Scrum teams.

What is regression testing in web-development? How does it relate to manual testing? Does it test usability, UI, localization or what? Which automation frameworks are used? How much time does it take? Why is it particulary important to automate regression testing?